# Upload pil image object in s3 using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, image-processing, boto3

I am trying to upload a pil object in S3 using boto3.

```
FileObj = bucket.Object(s3_file.key)
file_stream = io.BytesIO()
FileObj.download_fileobj(file_stream)
watermarked_image_obj = Image.open(file_stream)
FileObj.upload_fileobj(watermarked_image_obj,  ExtraArgs={'ACL':'public-read'})
```

But it showing an error like this.

```
   File "./Desktop/image_watermark/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3    
       /s3/inject.py", line 525, in upload_fileobj
   raise ValueError('Fileobj must implement read')
   ValueError: Fileobj must implement read
```

What should I do?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: `Image.open()` gives you image in memory but `upload_fileobj` need file-like object which has `read()`. If you only want to send image then you can treat it as normal file and use directly `file_stream` which should have `read()` - you don't have to load with `Image.open()`.

Comment: if you want to change image before upload then you should use again `BytesIO` with `image.write()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't test it but you should use again `BytesIO` to create file-like object

```py
FileObj = bucket.Object(s3_file.key)

# - download -

download_file_stream = io.BytesIO()

FileObj.download_fileobj(download_file_stream)
#download_file_stream.seek(0) # move to beginning of file
watermarked_image_obj = Image.open(download_file_stream)
image_format = watermarked_image_obj.format # format: JPG, PNG, etc.
 
# - upload -

upload_file_stream = io.BytesIO()

watermarked_image_obj.save(upload_file_stream, image_format) # format: JPG, PNG, etc.
#upload_file_stream.seek(0) # move to beginning of file
FileObj.upload_fileobj(upload_file_stream, ExtraArgs={'ACL':'public-read'})
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much for this!